# Proof of relation between partial derivatives with different variables kept constant

Tags: thermodynamics

Whilst proving that the isothermal coefficient in a hydrostatic system, $\kappa_T$, is greater than $0$, my professor used the following tool:
$$\left(\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_S=\left(\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_V+\left(\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V\left(\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S$$

He mentioned where it came from and wrote something related on the blackboard, but I couldn't copy it on time. So how'd this be proven? Maybe employing cyclic property or chain rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation is incorrect.  It should read:  $$\left(\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_S=\left(\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_T+\left(\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V\left(\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S$$T is constant on the partial derivative in the first term on the right.

Comment: And the equation can of course be obtained by expanding $dp$ in $V$ and $T$ as $dp = \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_TdV+\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_VdT$ and differentiating with respect to $V$ at constant $S$.

Comment: That's pretty straightforward, thank you both! And sorry for the typo.